# Having some trouble with CSS Flex Row as well as Table / Table Cell

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been trying to debug a CSS flex issue for a few hours. I need the three boxes in each row to have the same height. I've used flex quite a few times and think it might be an issue with floats but clearing them didn't seem to solve any obvious issues. It's likely that I'm overlooking something very simple.

[Dev Page with Float Issues](https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/conduct/index.php)

```css
.circle-box-table-container {
    width: calc(100% + 42px);
    margin: -10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-4.circle-box-alt-blue-border {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a fixed height in px? Also I pulled up devtools on your link and it looks like you have a typo in your html at <div class="circle-box-content-containter alt-blue-border"> not sure if that may be contributing to the problem or not.

Comment: I can't have a fixed height. I need the boxes to expand dynamically based on the box with the longest content. Thanks for finding the typo I'll fix it once I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you used height 100% inside your box. you need to modify some css,

```
.circle-box-content-text{
height: auto;
}

.circle-box-content-heading{
height: auto;
}

.circle-box-content-containter{
height: 100%;
}
```

do this way, hope your height issue will fix.